# Keep Ajax Connection Alive for 15 Minutes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to keep the connection from Ajax to PHP Script open so that my CSV loads successfully into the database. Currently it cut off at 30 seconds. Below is the JavaScript.

I cannot use php to set time out because RackSpace Load Balancer cut off Scripts that are inactive for 30 seconds.

```
(function() {

    var bar = $('.bar');
    var percent = $('.percent');
    var status = $('#status');

    $('form#bulk-upload').ajaxForm({
            beforeSend: function() {
                    status.empty();
                    var percentVal = '0%';
                    bar.width(percentVal)
                    percent.html(percentVal);
            },
            uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                    bar.width(percentVal)
                    percent.html(percentVal);
            //console.log(percentVal, position, total);
            },
            success: function() {
                    var percentVal = '100%';
                    bar.width(percentVal)
                    percent.html(percentVal);
            },
        complete: function(xhr) {
            data = xhr.responseText;
            var data = data.split("|");
            var code = $.trim(data[0]);
            var msg = $.trim(data[1]);
            if( code == 1 ){
                $("#ajax-msg").addClass("alert alert-success").html(msg);
            } else {
                $("#ajax-msg").addClass("alert alert-danger").html(msg);
            }
            return true; 
        }
    });
    })();
```

Comment: "...cut[s] off Scripts that are inactive for 30 seconds." Surely the php script wont be inactive if its parsing a csv and making database calls?

Comment: Yes, so is there a way that I can see the connection alive.

Comment: I don't think you can keep an AJAX connection 'open'.

Comment: websocket would be a good idea for uploading large data, wouldn't use PHP for this though.  And irrespective of if a loadbalancer closes the connection after 30 seconds, the PHP scripts should still be running on the server, probably better off creating a job on the server, then polling the job status every second via AJAX, if you need to use ajax. otherwise implement a websocket.

Comment: You can make the PHP script "active" by outputting just whitespace characters. Use `flush()` to force output.